# transfering msg.value from user to contract give error

Tags: solidity, evm

The transaction has been reverted [image]to the initial state. i get transaction failed everytime

Comment: Please, share source code as text.

Answer (score 2):

That is not the correct way to send ether from the user to the contract, you must do it in the call to buyCourse(), not inside. The contract cannot get ether from the user wallet, but receive it.

In your code, the contract is sending ether to itself, which is not possible and fails.

Look for the solution in the part where you call buyCourse()